# ActionBar Compat not showing logo on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to use the new ActionBar Compat provided in the last support-v7 lib.
Using the samples in the SuppportV7Demos, when i touch the "DISPLAY_USE_LOGO", icon doesn't change.

Since i can't make it work in my own app too, did anyone achieved this ?

```
ActionBarDisplayOptions.java

package com.example.android.supportv7.app;

public class ActionBarDisplayOptions extends ActionBarActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener, ActionBar.TabListener {
private View mCustomView;
private ActionBar.LayoutParams mCustomViewLayoutParams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.action_bar_display_options);

    findViewById(R.id.toggle_home_as_up).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.toggle_show_home).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.toggle_use_logo).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.toggle_show_title).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.toggle_show_custom).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.toggle_navigation).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.cycle_custom_gravity).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.toggle_visibility).setOnClickListener(this);

    // Configure several action bar elements that will be toggled by display options.
    mCustomView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_display_options_custom, null);
    mCustomViewLayoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setCustomView(mCustomView, mCustomViewLayoutParams);
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_options_actions, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    int flags = 0;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.toggle_home_as_up:
            flags = ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP;
            break;
        case R.id.toggle_show_home:
            flags = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME;
            break;
        case R.id.toggle_use_logo:
            flags = ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO;
            break;
        case R.id.toggle_show_title:
            flags = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE;
            break;
        case R.id.toggle_show_custom:
            flags = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM;
            break;
        case R.id.toggle_navigation:
            bar.setNavigationMode(
                    bar.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD
                            ? ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS
                            : ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            return;
        case R.id.cycle_custom_gravity: {
            ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = mCustomViewLayoutParams;
            int newGravity = 0;
            switch (lp.gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) {
                case Gravity.LEFT:
                    newGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                    break;
                case Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL:
                    newGravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                    break;
                case Gravity.RIGHT:
                    newGravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                    break;
            }
            lp.gravity = lp.gravity & ~Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK | newGravity;
            bar.setCustomView(mCustomView, lp);
            return;
        }
        case R.id.toggle_visibility:
            if (bar.isShowing()) {
                bar.hide();
            } else {
                bar.show();
            }
            return;
    }

    int change = bar.getDisplayOptions() ^ flags;
    bar.setDisplayOptions(change, flags);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
}
```

and :
    action_bar_display_options.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button android:id="@+id/toggle_home_as_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/toggle_home_as_up" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/toggle_show_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/toggle_show_home" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/toggle_use_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/toggle_use_logo" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/toggle_show_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/toggle_show_title" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/toggle_show_custom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/toggle_show_custom" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/toggle_navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/toggle_navigation" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/cycle_custom_gravity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cycle_custom_gravity" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/toggle_visibility"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/toggle_visibility" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the actionbarsherlock version of my app I was setting the icon and logo in the manifest.  After changing to ActionBarCompat the logo didn't show in the actionbar on Android 2.2, 2.3.x.

To make the logo show I set it in code

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
```

and removed 'android:logo="@drawable/logo_icon" ' from the manifest.

Tested on Android 2.2, 2.3.3 and 4.1.2.

Comment: it works even without removing the 'android:logo="@drawable/logo_icon" from the manifest.

Answer (score 7):

Setting the logo in `AndroidManifest.xml` does not update the action bar in older Android versions (before API 9), because there is no way to retrieve that value at runtime in those Android versions.

To change the icon to a logo in all Android versions you can style the action bar in `/res/values.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.AppActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
  <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
</style>
```